# Separate a number from text string into separate column (no separator between them)

Tags: r

I have a column with entries like AB1997-147, AB1997-150, AB2000-001 etc. What is the way to extract in a separate column only the 4 digit number between the letters 'AB' and the dash '-' symbol? I can separate the ABxxxx part from the rest using separate() from dplyr but I am not sure how to separate the number from the 'AB' part. Thank you.

Comment: `newcol = stringr::str_extract(oldcol, "(?<=AB)\\d+(?=-)")` or `stringr::str_extract(oldcol, "\\d{4}")`.

Comment: you can also run `gsub` on your column `gsub(pattern = "AB|(-[[:digit:]]+)", replacement = "", x = oldcol)` and assign it to the new column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data <- data.frame(col = c("AB1997-147", "AB1997-150", "AB2000-001"))

data %>% 
  mutate(AB_num = str_extract(col, "(?<=AB)\\d{4}"))

#         col AB_num
1 AB1997-147   1997
2 AB1997-150   1997
3 AB2000-001   2000
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stay in base R territory you can remove the parts of the string you don't need with `gsub`.

```r
data <- data.frame(col = c("AB1997-147", "AB1997-150", "AB2000-001"))

data$newcol <- strtoi(gsub(pattern = "AB|(-[[:digit:]]+)",
                           replacement = "",
                           x = data$col)))

#         col newcol
#1 AB1997-147   1997
#2 AB1997-150   1997
#3 AB2000-001   2000
```

`strtoi()` just converts the string to an integer. If you want to